# How to clear session of external website using PHP, JavaScript

Tags: php, session, iframe

I am loading an external website using iframe in my site. In iframe src URL, I am passing the username and password to login directly to the external website to show the registered content.

Now if I logout in my site, I need to clear the session of the external website too. I have the logout URL of the external website. Without knowing my site user (in background), I need to call this logout URL. Anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other site doesn't have CSRF protection you can do a bit of magic to make the request.

```
s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'http://url.to.other.site/logout?or=whatever';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Unless the response is valid javascript it will produce an error, but the request will be made in any case.

Answer (score 2):

you can't, think of the security implications if you could. (ps. iframes suck)